# instalacion de angular linux lite de 32 bits

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, linux

Instalé el nodejs (v4.2.6, mi pc es de 32 bits xd), el npm (v3.x.x) y cuando ejecuto el

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

me da

> /usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory....

alguien sabe que hacer ?? soy nuevo con linux , y en todo caso hay una forma alternativa de instalar angular en linux ?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Has mirado en google? [github](https://github.com/animetosho/Nyuu/issues/14) , [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320901/cannot-install-nodejs-usr-bin-env-node-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la opcion de instalar node 6 usando las instrucciones de esta web:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

En caso de que no puedas (o quieras) la unica solucion que se me ocurre es que tengas que crear un symlink entre la carpeta "real" de node y la que necesitas.
Ejecuta este comando en el terminal:
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`